# Cover entire client area with a 960.gs flexible grid layout

Tags: css, grid, 960.gs, fluid-layout

I'm using http://960.gs grid system/framework

I'm having some head-to-wall punching trying to make a flexible layout that allows me to cover the width and height of visitor's browser client area, specially in "height"... *Look at the following image*

[image: Grid Layout]

**So, the grid layout should cover everything and there shouldn't be any scrollbars. If user adjusts the size, grid should adapt, until a minimum width-height is reached**

Thanks for any tip/hack you can give me

Answer (score 0):

That particular grid is designed for fixed width 960px layouts and is not really suitable for fluid layouts. What you want is a percentage based grid. You might want to have a look at [Fluid 960 Grid System](http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/).

Comment: Tyom. I've generated a fluid grid using http://www.spry-soft.com/grids/ but my problem is to cover the entire height in browser's client area, and make it cover dinamically when window is resized